# The right format for phone number in résumé

Tags: resume, phone

I'm revisiting my résumé and updating portions that needs updating. I'm stuck at the phone number format. I did a quick Google search and found that the most common format is like this: `(+xx) xxx-xxx-xxxx`. I live in Egypt so the international country code is +20.

This implies that the part inside the parens is optional, if you're inside the same country. Here's the problem: if you're dialing from outside Egypt, you dial `+20 111-xxx-xxxx`. But, if you're dialing from inside Egypt you dial `0111-xxx-xxxx`. So the implication that the part in parens is incorrect.

How do I format such a number so that it is understandable to both international and local callers?

Comment: The standard here is "+20 (0)111-xxx-xxxx" but I'm voting to close this as off-topic as there's nothing really workplace related here.

Comment: Perhaps make two versions of the resume? One for job outside of Egypt and one for jobs in Egypt.

Comment: If your resume clearly says you're in Egypt and a prospective employer is also in Egypt, it's reasonable to assume he would know what prefixes ("+20", "0111") to use.

Comment: @PhilipKendall thanks for your reply. Also I didn't know where to post it, and when I searched for similar question I didn't find any, and then I searched for resume related questions and found they're posted here. That's why I posted it here too.

Comment: @DanPichelman I believe most of them would know, yes, but I'm asking to know if there's a better formatting that would be standardized. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If you want to write just one: if you write +20 1111, anyone from international will be able to reach you, and anyone inside Egypt should know that they can remove the +20 and add a zero (and I think that if you dial the international code from inside the country, it works nonetheless).

Comment: @mcknz is this acceptable in the resume?

Comment: @Kerkyra thank you. I might end up doing this, yes.

Comment: Why do you think people who read your resume do not know how to make a call? Is it common in Egypt for people to get so confused that you need to provide meta-information on how to interpret a phone number? Here in India, it is common to write a landline number as (+91) XX-YYYY-YYYY, where XX is area code. People who dial from India will skip the '+91' and prefix '0'. People who dial from a landline in the same area will skip both '(+91)' and 'XX' and not prefix '0'.

Comment: @MaskedMan I don't think they won't know how to make a call, but I'm simply asking to know if there's a better format to write it that other people use that it's considered a standard. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would simply state the full international number as it will work regardless of whether or not a caller international or local. It's a difference of only two characters.

- `+20 111-xxx-xxxx` is always going to work
- `0111-xxx-xxxx` is only going to work if the caller is from Egypt
- `(+20) 111-xxx-xxxx` requires callers to understand when to keep the prefix and additional knowledge of local callers (probable) about what to substitute the prefix with. If local callers opt for the international format you've essentially wasted 2 characters for nothing.
- `+20 (0) 111-xxx-xxxx` requires callers to understand when to leave out the part in parentheses (probable for local callers, potentially confusing for international callers).
- `+20/0 111-xxx-xxxx` technically correct but I've never seen this format used.

Again. The international format is *unambiguous*, *complete*, *universally usable* and *shorter* than any other format aside from the local-only format.

Comment: I just got another thought, but I don't know if it's acceptable. Is is possible to write it like this: (+2) 0111-xxx-xxxx ? It's right from a caller's point, but +2 isn't actually the country code.

Comment: @MahmoudAbdel-Mon'em I've personally never seen it. But that's likely because it doesn't apply to most prefixes. Switzerland for examples has +41 as international code and 0 as local code so this pattern wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

There's a difference between reference and usage -- between **knowing** what the phone number is, and actually **making** a call using that number.

This really depends on the audience for your resume. If you know that the recipient is familiar with the usage, then format the number according to the most common and standard format.

Another option, as mentioned by @DavidK in the comments, is to have two versions of your resume.

Maintenance of multiple versions of anything is always difficult, so you might also include both phone number formats on your resume, something like this:

> **Name**: Mahmoud Abdel-Mon'em
>
> **Email**: mymail@example.com
>
> **Phone (within Egypt)**: 0111-xxx-xxxx
>
> **Phone (outside Egypt)**: +20 111-xxx-xxxx

As long as you have multiple ways for people to contact you, however (including email and social media if applicable), the specific format of the phone number probably doesn't matter quite as much.